# How to transition between two engineered woods in different rooms with no bulky transition strip

Tags: flooring

I had engineered wood installed in entryway 3 years ago. I would like to change carpet in adjoining living-dining room to engineered wood that is same height and width just slightly different color. I would like to avoid the bulky transition strip since it is a large opening to the room.

Comment: Floating engineered wood?

Comment: Is it the same brand?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the same brand in both rooms, look for repair strips from the manufacturer. These would be basically zero-width fillers with tongues on both sides.

Otherwise, some carpentry is in order. Ideally you'd mill grooves into each board and use a biscuit of sorts to joint them, creating a mechanical connection which resists vertical shift. Use a good wood glue and be happy.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.mlcswoodworking.com/shopsite_sc/store/html/smarthtml/pages/bit_tongue_groove.html)</sub>